# How to pass user login details to Spring Boot Rest API using postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am creating an API using Spring Boot Rest, I want to restrict the API so only logged in users can access it. Now to test the API I am using postman, but how to pass the user details to the API?

Here is my code:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/", "/orders").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/order/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/order/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);

    }

    // create two users, admin and user
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Here is my access denied handler:

```
@Component
public class MyAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAccessDeniedHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                       HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                       AccessDeniedException e) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Authentication auth
                = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (auth != null) {
            logger.info("User '" + auth.getName()
                    + "' attempted to access the protected URL: "
                    + httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());
        }
        httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json");
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.print("Wrong user");

    }
}
```

When I try to access the API with URL as `order` and method as `DELETE` using `postman` and passing user login details using `Authorization` tab with `Basic Auth` and passing Username as `admin` and password as `password`, I am getting `Wrong user` message.

How to pass the user loin details to my API using `postman`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe form login is the default auth mechanism and you need to specify that you want to use Basic Auth.

Try this:

```
@Configuration
class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/", "/orders").permitAll()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/order/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/order/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
      .and()
      .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
    .and()  //added
    .httpBasic();  //added

  }

  // create two users, admin and user
  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
      .and()
      .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need is the following dependency (You might have it already):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Than you can create a user in your application.properties file:

```
security.user.name=username
security.user.password=password
```

If you are using Spring 2.0.0 M4 or higher use "spring.security".

Now go to Postman under "Authorization" use "Basic Auth" and fill in the credenrtials you have set in the properties file.

Hope this is what you are looking for. Good luck:)